# Dagger hilt get scope object in injected object

Tags: kotlin, dagger-hilt

How get scope object (like ViewModel, Fragment etc where I inject) in injected object?

I finded only @ActivityContext annotation that give you activity but i need ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
   @Inject lateinit var someObj: SomeInjectedObject
  //some code
}

class SomeInjectedObject @Inject constructor(){
// how can i get here view model link ?
}
```

I can just set it in init block but it looks like incorrect decision

```
@HiltViewModel
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    var someObj: SomeInjectedObject
) : ViewModel() {
  init{
     someObj.vm = this
  }
  //some code
}

class SomeInjectedObject @Inject constructor(){
   var vm: ViewModel
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't, if you need viewmodel method to be accessed inside another class beside activity/fragment, then that method should be come from another class not from viewmodel

Comment: @dayapangestu I need link to ViewModel in SomeInjectedObject (injected object in view model) for use CoroutineScope that used in PositionRateSource when data loaded

Comment: @dayapangestu no matter how i use it. I can redesign it so all SomeInjectedObject methods that i used in view model passed viewmodels link as param. But it looks no better than setter

Comment: if you only need coroutinescope on SomeInjectedObject, just pass it as parameter into SomeInjectedObject, provide coroutineScope from your module class, you dont need viewmodelScope to use coroutinescope in another class